# Convolution of signals $x[n]$ and $h[n]$

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

I would like to ask for details to fully understand the calculation of the convolution with the two discrete signals below

$$\begin{aligned} x[n] &= δ[n+1] + 2δ[n] + 2δ[n−2] + 3δ[n−3]\\ h[n] &= δ[n] + δ[n-1] \end{aligned}$$

By applying the staircase method I found the following

$$y[n] = [ 1 , 3, 2, 2, 5, 3 ]$$

but I am not sure I am right. I would be very grateful if anyone could clarify this.

Comment: What is the staircase method?  Why don't you show your work?

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. You should write $y$ using $\delta$, not as a mere list. When does that list start? You have discarded temporal information.